# Not sure how to restrict routes using meanjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, angular-ui-router

I am pretty new to the MEAN stack...
The current app I am building, I used meanjs and yeoman to scaffold it out.

I want users and I want admins to manage those users (create/delete users, add other admins). The way meanjs builds this is:

```
roles: {
type: [{
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin']
}],
default: ['user']
```

I added 'admin' into the array. Is this a good way to handle this or is there something more secure?

The main problem I am facing is I can't figure out how to secure certain routes to only admins. I understand this can be done with angular and with express/node but I have no idea how to implement either.

I have been googling for 3 days and I came across people building from scratch (looks nothing like my current code or folder structure), or not doing any type of route restriction/authorization/auth. I've also looked in the meanjs docs, not helpful at all.

Any advice, help, places to learn would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at MEAN.JS 0.4.0 version (master branch [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)) it already has implemented route restriction both in server and in client.

As you mentioned the User schema can have `user` and `admin` roles.

Regarding the server side you will have a `policies` directory which contains a js file specifying which routes are allowed, taking into account the roles the user accessing that route has. Those permissions are managed by a node module called node_acl. You can take a look at an example [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/articles/server/policies/articles.server.policy.js).

Regarding the client side, when you define the routes for your angular module (example [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/articles/client/config/articles.client.routes.js), note the `data: {roles: ['user', 'admin']}` in some of the routes), one way of checking if the user is allowed to access that route is to check his roles when the user goes to a specific route (or in other words when the event `$stateChangeStart` is triggered) which in MEAN.JS is happening in this [file](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/core/client/app/init.js).

You are probably using an older version of MEAN.JS, but maybe if you follow the examples in the latest version you can get it to work in your app.

Comment: I will check these out! Thank you for being descriptive and providing examples :)

Comment: My folder structure is much different. No idea why, I started this pretty recently.

I have no policies directory. So I am adding that server code to my 'users.authentication.server.controller.js' file. Unfortunately I am getting an error when I try to use the 'acl' module. Is this a dependency I need to have? I looked in te examples files and i don't see them using an acl dependency.

Comment: acl is being used [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/articles/server/policies/articles.server.policy.js) in the policies file, where the permissions are set. You are probably using meanjs 0.3.0 and in that version there was no permissions logic implemented :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://passportjs.org/ for authentication.

Scotch.io has a great tutorial for setting up your models and passport auth.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

After setting up Passport in your node app, you can easily secure your Angular views and API routes with middleware.

Good luck! Hope you find that reading helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will take a look